# jbpm 6.5 standalone web designer on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, jbpm

Dears,
I have downloaded the war: jbpm-designer-standalone-6.5.0.Final.war  at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jbpm/jbpm-designer-standalone/6.5.0.Final/

and then I deploy it in the tomcat, and now there's some problems in catalina.out,  and there's guide in the https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-designer.  I don't know how to fix.

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
Nov 16, 2016 11:39:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/arthur/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/designer.war
Nov 16, 2016 11:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/arthur/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/designer/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 16, 2016 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/designer]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid  FormsDocumentServlet in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3404)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1359)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more

Nov 16, 2016 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/arthur/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/designer.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/designer]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 16, 2016 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /home/arthur/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/designer.war has finished in 14,246 ms
Nov 16, 2016 11:39:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/arthur/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/ROOT